# how to get just category from Http response with unique value?

Tags: angular

I need to just get unique category from http response which Im getting as Json from API 
Here is my Code

```
export class FoodList implements OnInit{
    foodList:Food[]=[];
    p:Food[]=[];
    //name:string;

    constructor( private foodS:FoodService){}

    ngOnInit(){
    this.foodS.getAll().subscribe(allfood =>this.foodList=allfood);

    }
```

`foodList[]` giving me values but all with duplicate category I need to display only unique category .

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
        All
    </a>
    <div  *ngFor="let food of foodDetails ">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{food.category}} </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

service :

```
constructor( private http : HttpClient ){}

    getAll(): Observable<Food[]>{

    return this.http.get<Food[]>(this._url)


  }
```

Please suggest me any idea or how I can achieve it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of `foodList` ?

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/q/2218999/9766215 ?

Comment: Prachi I know but I'm getting values as response from server so confused that is JavaScript I want to do with Angular way

Comment: @Shreyas use that logic within a pipe https://angular.io/guide/pipes. And typescript is an extension of javascript, so you can use it here.

Comment: Prachi, Thank you, I gone through document I couldn't found any help

Comment: bug, that is huge list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ***map*** and ***filter*** but you need to change your ***UI***

```
<div  *ngFor="let food of foodDetails ">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{food}} </a>
</div>
```

and **code:**

```
  constructor(private foodS:FoodService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
    this.foodS.getAll().subscribe(allfood=> {
      this.foodList= allfood
        .map(cat => cat.category)
        .filter((x, i, a) => x && a.indexOf(x) === i);
    });
  }
```

Comment: This code is simpler than the one I wrote but... It is also not as optimized. @Shreyas said: "that is huge list" so I'm guessing that performance matters. Here you'll be mapping once onto `allfood`, then filtering onto it (which means looping through it again), and then using indexOf to know whether it's in the array or not (which is going to loop through the array as many times as there are element in the original array until it finds a match). So that's a lot. In my solution it'll only loop once over it.

Comment: but he just need category field, and what matter is simpler solution :) ,your answer gave lots of insight thanks for that also

Comment: "what matter is simpler solution"  when OP said that he has a huge list, I thought perf matters actually more than simpler solution. But yeah feel free to grab one of those solutions according to your needs Shreyas :)

Comment: valid point,but you're storing those huge values in array and again one more iteration to get just categories??,I would like to know about it just asking and not arguing with, it seems you have good understating please let me know also thank you in advance

Comment: No worries I was just trying to get a productive discussion too :) I'm storing into an array the final result and the unique value within a map. The map allows me to to avoid the indexOf (which is looping over and over again on the array) while accessing through a map is just super quick. (trying generating a map of 50.000 elements and access the last one vs doing the same with an array and indexOf you'll see). It's true that it's going to loop one more time: Within the view directly. But so do you there's not much we can do about that, we need to loop over it in the view for sure.

Comment: An from the view I do access to the category directly.

Comment: wow so much info made me think , I can not store again same result in `one more array`, it is better to store just category in array without  `JSON values` thank you guys.

Comment: You wouldn't store them "again". As you have objects, they're passed by reference. If you delete them from array, they wouldn't be available from the other. It doesn't take any memory except for the array instance itself which is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to keep your values within a stream as often as possible.

In other words, avoid that kind of things:

```
.subscribe(allfood =>this.foodList=allfood);
```

You should rather do:

```
export class FoodList implements OnInit {
  foodList$: Observable<Food[]>;

  constructor(private ghumaG: GhumaGhumaluService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.foodList$ = this.ghumaG
      .getAll()
      .pipe(map(foodList => Array.from(new Set(foodList))));
  }
}
```

2 things to notice here:
 - not assigning a value at a given time, just referencing an observable
 - I'm using `map` from rxjs to transform the value that we receive
 - I'm taking advantage of `Set` which is pure Javascript to get an array containing only the different values

If you have objects instead of primitive types, you can just do the following instead:

Define a function to keep only unique values based on their ID:

```
export const keepUniqueValuesById = <T>(arr: T[]): T[] =>
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, item) => {
      if (!acc.dictionnary.has(item.id)) {
        acc.dictionnary.set(item.id, item);
        acc.finalArray.push(item);
      }

      return acc;
    },
    { finalArray: [], dictionnary: new Map<string, any>() }
  ).finalArray;
```

Use that function when mapping onto your data:

```
export class FoodList implements OnInit {
  foodList$: Observable<Food[]>;

  constructor(private ghumaG: GhumaGhumaluService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.foodList$ = this.ghumaG
      .getAll()
      .pipe(map(foodList => keepUniqueValuesById(foodList)));
  }
}
```

In the end, in your view you can do:

```
<div class="list-group" *ngIf="foodList$ | async as foodList">
  <div *ngFor="let foodItem of foodList ">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{foodItem.category}} </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you once gain best answer but I would like go with second answer